# Using Conditional Symbol inside .csproj

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Inside the .csproj there are some constants defined like this:

```
<DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;ANDROID;GLES;OPENGL;OPENAL</DefineConstants>
```

Then later in the project there's an itemgroup

```
<ItemGroup>
<EmbeddedNativeLibrary Include="..\ThirdParty\Dependencies\openal-soft\libs\armeabi-v7a\libopenal32.so">
  <Platforms>Android,Ouya</Platforms>
  <Link>libs\armeabi-v7a\libopenal32.so</Link>
</EmbeddedNativeLibrary>
<EmbeddedNativeLibrary Include="..\ThirdParty\Dependencies\openal-soft\libs\armeabi\libopenal32.so">
  <Platforms>Android,Ouya</Platforms>
  <Link>libs\armeabi\libopenal32.so</Link>
</EmbeddedNativeLibrary>
<EmbeddedNativeLibrary Include="..\ThirdParty\Dependencies\openal-soft\libs\x86\libopenal32.so">
  <Platforms>Android,Ouya</Platforms>
  <Link>libs\x86\libopenal32.so</Link>
</EmbeddedNativeLibrary>
```

I want this ItemGroup to be included only when the constant OPENAL is defined, regardless of debug or release. How can I do this?

```
<ItemGroup Condition="XXXXXX" >
```

What would XXXXXX be?

Comment: Found the answer... <ItemGroup Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('OPENAL'))">

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The syntax for a condition that checks if a Constant is defined is: (in this case OPENAL)

```
<ItemGroup Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('OPENAL'))">
```

Comment: Thanks, it solves my problem when I have two configurations. One for Debug and second for Release and can use one condition for both when a constant is defined at project's 'conditional compilation symbols' build page.
Don't have to do this: Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'TEST Debug' OR '$(Configuration)' == 'TEST Release'" but Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('TEST'))".

Comment: The condition will also be fulfilled when checking for 'OPEN', and that's probably not expected, so you'd better check for ';OPEN;'.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `<Choose>` element to create conditional blocks in msbuild / .csproj files 
if you want to do more sophisticated conditional processing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164282.aspx

Edited: Angle brackets had disappeared.